# How to use react-rating package's events?

Tags: reactjs

I want to use react-rating (https://gist.github.com/wen-long/8644243) to implement a book review page, with adding

`<Rating />`

in my own component, I'm able to show a rating elements on the page, but I don't know how to make the onChage event and onClick event available on this page. My code now is something like this.

```
var Rating = require('react-rating');

class BookPage extends Component {
  handleRate(rate) {
    "use strict";
    console.log("the rate is:"+rate);
  }

  render() {
    book = this.props.document;
    console.log("book:"+book)
    //console.log(util.inspect(book, false, null));

    return (
      <div className="BookPage">

        <div style={{maxWidth: "300px"}}>
          <Accounts.ui.LoginForm />
        </div>

        <FlashContainer component={FlashMessages}/>

        <BookItem book={book}/>

        <Rating />   // how to add events ?

        <div className="comments-thread">
          <h4 className="comments-thread-title">BookPosts</h4>
          <ListContainer
            collection={Posts}
            publication="bookPosts.list"
            terms={{book_id: book._id}}
            limit={5}
            joins={Posts.getJoins()}
            component={BookPostsList}
                />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: `<Rating onClick={rating => this.handleRate(rate)} />` ?

Comment: @azium thanks for replying, I added this code and the browser console reported an uncaught reference error: rate is not defined. How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @azium comments is *correct*. You need to pass a function that expects a `rate` as a parameter.

The error you get is because the function you are passing to the `onClick` property is not using the `rating` parameter but an undefined one (`rate`). Try this instead:

```
<Rating onClick={rate => this.handleRate(rate)} />
```

Right now react-rating provides three [callbacks](https://github.com/dreyescat/react-rating#callbacks):

- `onChange` Called when the selected rate is changed.
- `onClick` Called when a rate is clicked.
- `onRate` Called when a rate is entered or left.

All of them accept the same type of function:

```
function (rate) {
  console.log(rate);
}
```

Or using arrow function:

```
rate => console.log(rate);
```